# Run Cypher at starting point from node(1)

Tags: java, cypher, node-neo4j

I don't know why I create a graph in Neo4j, it always have node[0] containing nothing, so when using For loop  for Iterator result, I got some exceptions like:

```
  'title' property not found for NodeImpl#0.
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.newPropertyNotFoundException(Primitive.java:184)
  ....
```

How can I deal with this problem?? I'm thinking use a Cypher query that have a starting point from node[1], but I don't know how to make this query or ignore node[0] when looping?

Answer (score 0):

You can either delete node 0 to get a clean database, or check for the existence of that property prior to accessing it, `node.hasProperty()`, http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0-M02/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#hasProperty(java.lang.String)